# How can I change a property to a different value, every time I create a new object from that class?

Tags: c#, object, properties

Today I started a console project with C#. 
My idea is to set up a class for every card there is in a standard deck of 52 cards. 
I'm now at implementing my first card "Two" so the card with the value of 2. 
**The problem is a deck contains 4 cards of "Two's" any with a different "color" (eg. club, diamond, heart, spade). So I have to keep track of what the card object I will create later on has which color on it.** 
I absolutely don't know how to do this?

I googled a bit and **my idea is to switch the color somehow everytime I create a new object to:

club --> diamond --> hearth --> spade** (then it starts from the beginning when I create a 2nd deck) because a blackjack game contains 6 x a deck of 52 cards.

This is my class so far:

```
class Two : ICard // thats the card with the value of "One"; 
{
    // in a deck of 52 cards there are 4 cards with "Two" in each color: club, diamond, heart, spade

    public string Name { get => Name;  private set => Name = value; }
    public int Value { get => Value;  private set => Value = value; }
    public int MaxIncludedInDeck { get => MaxIncludedInDeck; private set => MaxIncludedInDeck = value; }
    public string CardColor { get => CardColor; private set => CardColor = value; }

    public Two()
    {
        Name = "One";
        Value = 1;
        MaxIncludedInDeck = 4;

        // TODO: Figure out how to set one object to club, one to diamond, one to hearth and one to spade


    }
}
```

It just implements an interface with the same methods (I'm practicing the OOP by using an interface).

**Maybe you can lead me into the right direction** and tell me a few ideas how to tackle that problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why should you have a class for Two, Three, ... and not just a Card class that has a Value property that can be two, three

Comment: the classic way to do this is to have a Card class, with attributes Rank and Suit

Comment: So your idea is to create a card class and then give it a property of value and color? Then instantiate a deck with a lot of this cards with a for loop and everytime I change the variables I pass into the constructor?

Comment: You may be confusing the concepts of classes and instances. A class defines a type of thing (like a Card with properties Value and Suit), while each instance of that thing is an instantiation of that class with its own property values (like a Card for which Value = 2 and Suit = Spades). Defining one Card class (as Ashkan described) and then creating ("new"ing) however many instances of that class you need sounds like the direction you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, I was too slow. Yeah, GeraltDieSocke, that sounds like a good start. :-)

Comment: Yep ok I will rewrite the program then. Would you when you create the deck instantiate every card of the deck manually or is it better to find out some sort of algorithm that figures out what values it should give to the constructor so the deck will be built like it should be? Thanks for the help guys I think you saved me a lot of "bad" work. I will reconsider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:
Create a Card class with a constructor that takes the color and value as a parameter. Also create a Deck class that will contain all your 52 Cards and it will be responsible to instantiate your cards. Below you can find some sample code.

```
public enum CardColor
{
    Club =0,
    Diamond =1,
    Hearth  = 2,
    Spade = 3
}
public class Card
{
    public CardColor CardColor { get; set; }
    public int Value {get;set;}

    public Card(CardColor cardColor,int value) {
        CardColor = cardColor;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class Deck
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();
    //also instead on having a method to initialize the Deck you can do that
    // in the constructor of the Deck class
    public void InitilizeDeck()
    {
        foreach (var cardColor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardColor))) {
            for (int i = 1; i<=10;i++)
            {
                Cards.Add(new Card((CardColor)cardColor, i));
            }
        }
    }
}

  //then use the Deck class like that
  var deck = new Deck();
  deck.InitilizeDeck();
  var cards = deck.Cards;
```

Comment: Ok man that's just very smart. Thx for this. I have one little question to your code. I went through every line and read the docs to Enum (I'm very new to programming obviously :P ) and it makes sense to me.
The snippet I don't understand is this: (CardColor)cardColor - can you explain to me what this does exactly?
According to the documentation I would have tried it this way: 
`Cards.Add(new Card(CardColor.cardColor, i));
`

Comment: At that point the cardColor variable is being seen as of type object, we need to help the compiler to understand that this is of type CardColor, so i'm doing a cast to CardColor (CardColor)cardColor the parenthesis before the variable is where the casting is taking place. Please have a look here at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions